# Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:textColorHint' with parameter type int

Tags: android

I am trying to use data binding to set the `textColorHint` on `<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>`  view as in

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/text_input_layout_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/text_input_margin_bottom"
            android:hint="@{FieldHandlers.hasValidSpaces(account.firstName)? @string/first_name : @string/invalid_firstname}"
            app:textColorHint="@{FieldHandlers.hasValidSpaces(account.firstName)? @android:color/holo_red_light : @android:color/holo_red_light}"/>
```

however it gives the following error message:

```
Error:(70, 38) Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:textColorHint' with parameter type int on android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.
```

Is there a way I can use databinding with this property? It works if i pass in a color literal or a `@color/myColor` reference directly.

Comment: change the "app:textColorHint" to "android:textColorHint"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need this answer. But that attr doesn't work because it hasn't a setter provided in `TextInputLayout.class`. And as thats an sdk class - you aren't allowed to change it. The problem resides here, inside constructor, while parsing `TintTypedArray` :

```
if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.TextInputLayout_android_textColorHint)) {
        mDefaultTextColor = mFocusedTextColor =
                a.getColorStateList(R.styleable.TextInputLayout_android_textColorHint);
    }
```

You can try to use TextInputLayout.setHintTextAppearance() it works within binding.

***WARNING : But be aware there are behaviour changes introduced within support lib version 28.***

Looks like **error text color** and **hint text color** now are always the same in error state(if you will call `TextInputLayout.setError()`)